# If $f(x)=f(y)$ implies that $g(x)=g(y)$ is $g$ a function of $f$?

Tags: functions

Let $f: {\mathbb R}^n\to {\mathbb R}^p$ and $g: {\mathbb R}^n \to {\mathbb R}^q$ be two non-constant functions such that: $f(x)=f(y)$ implies that $g(x)=g(y)$, can we say that $g$ a function of $f$?

This is: $g(x)= h(f(x))$ for some function $h$.

Comment: How about a piece-wise function? Must $f$ and $g$ be continuous?

Comment: @AniruddhVenkatesan I am not necessarily assuming continuity. I have only proven that property in general. I just wonder if there is such implication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define 
$$h(x) = \left\{ 
\begin{array}{lc}
g(z) & \mbox{ if there exists some } z \mbox{ such that } f(z)=x \\
\mbox{ anything} & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.$$

Show that the given condition implies that $h$ is well defined, that is it does not depend on the choice of $z$.

Then, by definition 
$$h(f(x))=g(x) \forall x \in \mathbb R^d$$

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear. But I'm gonna go on a limb here and assume that when you say "$g$ is a function of $f$" you mean as a composition, i.e. you're asking whether we can write that $g(x)=h(f(x))$ with some new function $h$. In that case, the answer is yes.

So, let's say we're given two functions $f:A\to B$ and $g:A\to C$, and we know that $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $g(x)=g(y)$ for any $x,y\in A$. Then indeed we can construct a function $h:B\to C$ such that $g=h\circ f$, i.e. $g(x)=h(f(x))$ for all $x\in A$.

Here's the definition of $h$. Take an arbitrary $z\in\operatorname{Range}(f)$. This means that $z=f(x)$ for some $x\in A$. Define $h(z)=g(x)$. Note that this definition may depend on the choice of $x$, but thanks to the given condition it doesn't! Indeed, if we have two different elements $x,y\in A$ such that $f(x)=z$ and $f(y)=z$, then from $f(x)=f(y)$ we know that $g(x)=g(y)$, giving the same well-defined value for $h(z)$.

One remaining technicality is to define $h(z)$ for all remaining $z\in B\setminus\operatorname{Range}(f)$, and we can set those to be equal to anything we want.

Now, by the very definition this function satisfies $g(x)=h(f(x))$, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

More general: Let $f\colon X\to Y, g\colon X\to Z$ be mappings such that for all $x,y\in X$ the condition $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $g(x)=g(y)$. Then we may define $h:Y\to Z$ by $h(c):=g(x)$ if $c=f(x)$ for some $x\in X$ and arbitrary if $c \not\in f(X)$. By assumption $h$ is well defined, i.e., a function. And by construction $g(x)=h(g(x))$ for all $x\in X$.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that why you mean by "$g$ is a function of $f$" is "there exists a function $\mathfrak{F}$ such that $g=\mathfrak{F}(f)$".
$$\bigl(\forall x,y:f(x)=f(y)\implies g(x)=g(y)\bigr)\implies\exists \mathfrak{F}:g=\mathfrak{F}(f)$$

Consider $f(x)=x$. Any function $g$ having the same domain as $f$ will satisfy the first half of the above assertion. No matter what metafunction $\mathfrak{F}$ we examine, there will be functions $g$ satisfying the first half but not the second half of our assertion, so the assertion must be false.

**So the answer to your question is no.** Except possibly for some trivial and pathological universes of values for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Isn't $\mathfrak{F}=g$ working in your example?

Comment: No. That wouldn't even make sense; the domain (and range) of $\mathfrak{F}$ is the space of functions like $f$ and $g$.

Comment: That said, it's not clear that my interpretation of the question is consistent with everyone else's.

Comment: If you consider $\mathfrak{F}$ to be a function from some space of functions, to some space of functions, then the answer is trivially yes. You simply pick $\mathfrak{F}$ to be the constant function $\mathfrak{F}$. All you need is the domain of $\mathfrak{F}$ to contain $f$ and the range to contain $g$... and since the question is bout the existence of such $\mathfrak{F}$ you can pick the domain and range to be anything.

Comment: no. Suppose $f:\Bbb{I}\mapsto\Bbb{I}$. If $\mathfrak{F}(f)=f$, then for most $f$ $g(x)=2f(x)$ will break our assertion.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I'll try to clarify.

Comment: Why do you assume that $\mathfrak{F}(f)=f$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88551/discussion-between-shapeofmatter-and-n-s).

Answer (score -1):

If $\forall x : \not \exists y, s.t. f(x) = f(y)$, then the claim is true, but $f$, $g$, could be pretty anything

Comment: (a) The claim is true regardless. (b) Your quantifiers don't make sense. It's impossible to have "$\forall x : \not \exists y, \text{ s.t. } f(x) = f(y)$", because $y=x$ always satisfies $f(x)=f(y)$. You probably meant "$\forall x : \not \exists y, \text{ s.t. } x\ne y \text{ and } f(x) = f(y)$".